# Why is Microsoft Excel 2010 Showing a file open by another user when it isn't?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to open a file which tell me that it is open by another user and offers as read only. However, no-one is accessing the file.

Yes, the file is available to more than one user but IS NOT open.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are happy to help, but your question lacks sufficient detail to do so. Please take a minute to read ***[ask]***, then update your question with more details about your operating system, what you have tried and what research you have done.

Comment: Don't be so sure.. one way to test (assuming the file is on a windows machine) - Remote desktop or login to the PC where the files is located, choose "Computer Management" and then check "Shared Folders" and "Open Files" or "Sessions" chances are there are some entry there.

Comment: You are going to need to provide a little more detail on this.  For example, what user is the supposed workbook opened to?

Answer (score 1):

When in Excel shared files, sometimes the users do not close out properly before shutting down etc.  Excel thinks they are still connected.  If you go to  - View, -Share Workbook, it will list all the users, If you know for a fact that no one else is in it, you can remove them.  This will not remove them from using the workbook in the future, it just removes that link that didn't get shut completely.

Comment: If you get a read only you will need to have someone that is "logged in" do the above to get it back on track.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by opening the file, unshare, save with different filename, share, delete old file, then rename new file back to the old one.  You can save it to your local drive, then copy to the network location.